# Importing data with engineering notation into Matlab

Tags: matlab, nan, notation, xlsread

I've got a .xls file and I want to import it into Matlab by xlsread function..I get NaNs for numbers with engineering notation..like I get NaNs for 15.252 B or 1.25 M 
Any suggestions?

Update: I can use `[num,txt,raw] = xlsread('...')` and the raw one is exactly what I want but how can I replace the Ms with (*10<sup>6</sup>)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you could extract everything from excel in a cell array using

```
[~,~,raw] = xlsread('MyExcelFilename.xlsx')
```

Then you could write a simple function that returns a number from the string based on 'B', 'M' and so on. Here is such an example:

```
function mynumber = myfunc( mystring )
% get the numeric part 
my_cell = regexp(mystring,'[0-9.]+','match');
mynumber = str2double(my_cell{1});
% get ending characters
my_cell = regexp(mystring,'[A-z]+','match');
mychars = my_cell{1};
% multiply the number based on char
switch mychars
    case 'B'
        mynumber = mynumber*1e9;
    case 'M'
        mynumber = mynumber*1e6;
    otherwise
end

end
```

Of course there are other methods to split the numeric string from the rest, use what you want. For more info see the `regexp` documentation. Finally use `cellfun` to convert cell array to numeric array:

```
my_array = cellfun(@myfunc,raw);
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei.. I wanted to know is there a built-in function for formatting it seems there isn't such a F....

Comment: your code works well for a cell array (our imported raw) only if all cells have chars (M or B) what if we have a raw = {'50M','2.22M',20;'5.258B', 50, 10} where there are some elements without char? thanks

Comment: You could make an isempty check: `if isempty(my_cell) mychars = ''; else mychars = my_cell{1}; end` The switch will go in the otherwise condition and do nothing with the number.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer....note that we have 2 kinds of numbers in our cells: {'100', 100 } or '100' and [100] your code works for the first number but not the other..... I think it's a problem in the first regexp function, thank you again.

Comment: right, forgot about that case. just put `if isnumeric(mystring) mynumber = mystring; return end` at the very beginning of the function

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

> Matlab does not offer any built-in formatting of strings in engineering format.

Source: http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/892-engineering-notation-printed-into-files

In the source you will find also function which would be helpful for you.

Comment: Hi..yes 1.25M stands for 1.25x 10^-6..I've got little experience in programming and I know how to do it the hard way in excel but I want to know whats the trick in matlab!

Comment: I see. From my expierience we always called engineering notation numbers in format like : 2.7e-6. I don't know any function that can help you with it. You can write your own function by loading it as a string and changing it. Good luck!

Comment: 2.7e-6 is in scientific notation..thanks but I won't lose hope for a simpler solution..you know its matlab!

Comment: I found this topic on mathworks forum:
http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/892-engineering-notation-printed-into-files
I think it would be useful for you.